# Software for creating and delivering a Podcast

Tags: gratis, video, audio, podcast

I am working with a few others from the network to set up a *not formally* affiliated with SE podcast.  We were wondering what software to use with the following considerations in mind.

- 4 Geographically separated users

  - Users need to video conference during the recording of the podcast
- The final podcast with be both video and audio, posting to YouTube, 4 talking heads
- Free software (though the perfect software I'd be willing to pay for)
- Preferably MP3 Audio and MP4 Video (willing to consider other options though)

Ideally one piece of software that can allow for video conferencing and both audio and video record the conversation.

Realistically I am guessing we are looking at 2-3 pieces of software.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at google hangout?
It has video capture, you can put your desktop in the feed to show stuff that you want, and it publishes directly to your youtube channel...

http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/create-podcasts-with-google-hangouts-on-air/

http://schoolofpodcasting.com/google-hangouts-as-a-podcasting-solution-ray-ortega/

Also you could invite people to observe the podcast recording live, kind of like a show.

Then after the show is done you download the video and extract the audio for the audio version.
Very minimal work.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I'll repeat my solution here:

- VSee to do the chat *and record* separate streams for each user. (Note: I'm associated with VSee Lab Inc.)
- meanwhile make separate high-quality audio recordings locally on a separate device (optional).
- use screen capture or a local camera or just follow the outline to note which documents are being presented when, as that's not recorded.
- cheap or free video editing software is discussed elsewhere.  With the Adobe CC subscription including everything I'm back to Premiere since everything else I'm bought for reasonable price is lacking.
- use ffmpeg command line to change the mkv containers to mp4 or mov or whatever without transcoding the streams. Premiere is rather limited in what in *inputs*.  Open and free software will generally take mkv though.  Free (for non pro use) of traditional pro tools (like DaVinci Resolve) will be even more limited.
- I also use ffmpeg for final encoding, rather than Adobe’s supplied encoder.  I have my preferred parameters for lib x264 and use a 3D temperal smoothing filter.